# Node.js and sequelize-typescript - data access objects and business objects

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am using the [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript) in my Node.js service

I have the `Category` class which maps to category table

```ts
import { Model, Table, Column } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table
export class Category extends Model<Category>{

    @Column
    name: string
}
```

I also have `CategoryController` and `CategoryService`

```ts
export class CategoryController {

    ...

    async getAll(request: Request, response: Response) {
        let categories = await this.categoryService.getCatergories(); 
        response.json(categories)
    }
}

export class CategoryService {

    async getCatergories(): Promise<Category[]> {
        let categories = await Category.findAll<Category>()
        return categories
    }

}
```

And everything is as it should be.

But returning a `Category` to the controller allows it to use the use the **inherited methods** from the model class like:

```ts
export class CategoryController {

    ...

    async getAll(request: Request, response: Response) {
         let categories = await this.categoryService.getCatergories();

        // Remove associated row in the database
        categories[0].destroy()

        response.json(categories)
    }
}
```

I was thinking to create a `CategoryModel` class like this:

```ts
export class CategoryModel {
    id : number 
    name : string
}
```

And modify all methods in `CategoryService` to return `CategoryModel` instances instead of `Category` and rename `Category` to `CategoryEntity`

What is the best way to deal with such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toJSON()` of `Category` instance to get "a JSON representation" of the instance.

See sequelize docs for more information: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-toJSON

Additionally you could add an interface to achieve type safety for the return value of `toJSON()` instead of defining another class:

```
interface ICategory {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Table
export class Category extends Model<Category> implements ICategory{

    @Column
    name: string
}
```

Using `toJSON()`:

```
Category.findOne(result => {
  const category: ICategory = result.toJSON();
});
```